# same Linq for two tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to do something like this,

My two tables have the same signature, but different class so It suppose to work but it is not working.

```
var myTable;

if (booleanVariable == true)
{
     myTable = table1;
}
else
{
     myTable = table2;
}


var myLinq1 = from p in myTable
          join r in myOtherTable
          select p;
```

In this case, I have to initialize myTable

I have tried also,

```
var myTable= table2;

if (booleanVariable == true)
{
     myTable = table1;
}

var myLinq1 = from p in myTable
          join r in myOtherTable
          select p;
```

then var is type table2, then it can't be changed to table1 type.

I need help, I don't want to make a copy paste of all the code. the linq query is huge, and it s nested with 5 or 6 queries. also I have to do this on 12 different methods.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Now sorry I have to say this but I think that's an ugly, ugly, ugly SQL design. If you have two tables with the "same signature" (which I take to mean same columns) then there just has to be a discriminator column somewhere, not two tables.

Comment: they come from a very different source, so I better put then in a different table. probably you can't understand with so little information, but believe me, I did it with only one table, and It didn't work. my queries were very very big. so I changed the design and It worked for the final result. but I am having troubles Inserting the data. the data is exactly the same, but It has a very different meaning. thanks for the comment, but I already tried it

Comment: You were absolutely right. I have a mistake, thanks a lot Jon, I have to change a little bit my program, but It worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work, never tried it, but...

If both classes can implement the same interface or share a base class, could you maybe do:

```
var q = (booleanVariable) 
    ? from p in myTable1 select (ISomeInterface)p 
    : from p in myTable2 select (ISomeInterface)p;
```

If you use this often, you can put this into its own method - I believe it will return IQueryable<ISomeInterface>.

Then connect to the rest of the LINQ query using the LINQ methods instead of the LINQ C# syntax (i.e. OrderBy() instead of orderby).  I just don't know if LINQ-to-SQL will be smart enough to translate this into the correct SQL query.

But I agree with Jon's comment - this is probably bad design, and should be revisited.  If you can't reorganize the tables themselves, and if you only need read access, how about a view that unions the two tables together, then tie that view into your LINQ-to-SQL structure.

Comment: This items conteins Dates, and those dates changes states. I have to find the latest time that the state was changed. it made my queries horrible, because the latest changed not necessarily is the latest change on certain column. I am going to try your method and rethink about the design, when more than one people think the same I have to check. thanks four your answer.

Comment: It worked for the first query but in the second nested query the same error appears, there is not implicit conversion between type table1 and type table 2

Comment: thanks a lot Joe, I am changing my sql. I had a mistake, but I think I am on time.